# Making dyanamic link in dot net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want a functionality in which i want following thing:

when i open a page created by me for download, it should dynamically create links for all the documents present in particular directory.

for eg: if i have folder at web server as /download/document
and i have following document in this folder

a.txt
b.txt
c.doc
d.pdf

now when i open page then i should have 4 links each for these of documents n when i click on this link, the file can be downloaded

Comment: Did you try to write a code? Did you think any algorithm? Stackoverflow.com != Freelancer.com :(

Comment: no i dont have any idea for this thats why i am asking that how could i do that as there can be any number of files in that folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("Path to folder")` you can get list of files directory contains and `Request.PhysicalPath.Substring(0, Request.PhysicalPath.LastIndexOf("\\")))` will get you the physical path to the folder that contains your aspx file.
Then iterating through each file and using Request.Url you can generate download link.

Comment: thanks for the information, if possible can u give me a sample code so that i can use it

Comment: here it goes, though it only prints the download path you need to modify this code to generate anchor tag for each file.

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Request.PhysicalPath.Substring(0, Request.PhysicalPath.LastIndexOf("\\")));

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            sb.Append(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(0, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));
            sb.Append(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));
            sb.Append("<br/>");
        }
        Response.Write(sb.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

How about just enabling [directory browsing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725840%28WS.10%29.aspx) in IIS? It ain't pretty, but it'll get the job done in 10 seconds. :)

Answer (score 0):

additional to Waqas answer, you can create a panel (design time), then loop through all files in a specific directory, and create a Hyperlink Object for each file and assign the NavagationURL for it, and then add the hyperlink control to the panel

I guess this should helps